# Pandas fill row values using previous period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

***One additional note to address the problem better**, in the actual data set there is also a column called store and the table can be grouped by store, date & product, When I tried the pivot solution and the cartesian product solution it did not work, **is there a solution that could work for 3 grouping columns? Also the table has millions of rows.***

Assuming a data frame with the following format:

```
d = {'product': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'], 'amount': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2], 'date': ['2020-6-6', '2020-6-6', '2020-6-6', 
'2020-6-7', '2020-6-7']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

---

```
print(df)
 product  amount  date
0     a     1      2020-6-6
1     b     2      2020-6-6
2     c     3      2020-6-6
3     a     5      2020-6-7
4     b     2      2020-6-7
```

Product c is no longer present on the date 2020-6-7, I want to be able to calculate things like percent change or difference in the amount of each product.

For example: `df['diff'] = df.groupby('product')['amount'].diff()`

But in order for this to work and show for example that the difference of c is -3 and -100%, c would need to be present on the next date with the amount set to 0

This is the results I am looking for:

```
print(df)
 product  amount  date
0     a     1      2020-6-6
1     b     2      2020-6-6
2     c     3      2020-6-6
3     a     5      2020-6-7
4     b     2      2020-6-7
5     c     0      2020-6-7
```

Please note this is just a snipped data frame, in reality there might be many date periods, I am only looking to fill in the product and amount in the first date after it has been removed, not all dates after.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `pivot` then `unstack`

```
out = df.pivot('product','date','amount').fillna(0).unstack().reset_index(name='amount')
       date product  amount
0  2020-6-6       a     1.0
1  2020-6-6       b     2.0
2  2020-6-6       c     3.0
3  2020-6-7       a     5.0
4  2020-6-7       b     2.0
5  2020-6-7       c     0.0
```

Comment: Hi, I just made an edit, while this solution did work for the dataset above, is there a way to have it work if the table also has a column called store, which mean its can be grouped by store, date & product.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to explicitly expose the missing values and combine with [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill the missing values with 0:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
# import janitor
df.complete(['date', 'product']).fillna(0)

       date product  amount
0  2020-6-6       a     1.0
1  2020-6-6       b     2.0
2  2020-6-6       c     3.0
3  2020-6-7       a     5.0
4  2020-6-7       b     2.0
5  2020-6-7       c     0.0
```

Comment: how does this work, does it add new methods to the pandas lib directly or do you have to create a pyjanitor object?

Comment: Once the module is imported, the methods are `added` or  `registered` as pandas methods directly. So no need to create any pyjanitor object. They are just convenient wrappers of pandas methods/functions

Comment: @sammywemmy I tried this on a a small dataset, but when I tried it on a full dat set I got the following error : "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.86 TiB for an array with shape (3, 19418, 150, 58621) and data type int32"

Comment: depending on the path taken, a cartesian product is generated(similar to pd.MultiIndex.from_product), which is used to reindex ... what is the size of your data? Does it have duplicates?

Comment: it has over 5 millions rows, when grouped by store and date product does not have duplicates, but as individual columns yes product, store and date have duplicates @sammywemmy

Comment: i think it is the cartesian product that is causing the issue. If you dont mind, can you add more rows to the data, and a bit more explanation. I (or someone else) could possibly try and see if there is a better way than creating cartesian product - cartesian is not effective especially for such *large* data

Answer (score 0):

another way is to do create a cartesian product of your products & dates, then join that to your main dataframe to get the missing values.

```
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
#ensure you have a proper datetime object.

s = pd.merge( df[['product']].drop_duplicates().assign(ky=-1), 
         df[['date']].drop_duplicates().assign(ky=-1),
         on=['ky']
        ).drop('ky',1)

df1 = pd.merge(df,s,
         on = ['product','date']
         ,how='outer'
).fillna(0)
```

---

```
print(df1)

  product  amount       date
0       a     1.0 2020-06-06
1       b     2.0 2020-06-06
2       c     3.0 2020-06-06
3       a     5.0 2020-06-07
4       b     2.0 2020-06-07
5       c     0.0 2020-06-07
```

Comment: Hi, I just made an edit, while this solution did work for the dataset above, is there a way to have it work if the table also has a column called store, which mean its can be grouped by store, date & product