# Pandas fill values using previous period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming a data frame with the below format:

**A few important notes about the data, the dataset is very large, 10's of millions of rows so the solution would need to scale. There are thousands of unique stores and thousands of unique products and each store has data across multiple dates, more than the two shown in the simple example data set**

Update to this original question since there were some clarity issues:
[Pandas fill row values using previous period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144671/pandas-fill-values-using-previous-period)

```
d = {'store': ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2'], 'product': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'], 'amount': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3], 'date': ['2020-6-6', '2020-6-7', '2020-6-7', 
    '2020-6-6', '2020-6-6','2020-6-7']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


print(df)
    store  product   amount   value    date
0     s1      a        1        1    2020-6-6
1     s1      a        2        2    2020-6-7
2     s1      b        3        3    2020-6-7
3     s2      c        5        5    2020-6-6
4     s2      b        2        2    2020-6-6
5     s2      b        3        3    2020-6-7
```

For store S2, product c is no longer present on the date 2020-6-7, I want to be able to calculate things like percent change or difference in the amount of each product.

For example: df['diff'] = df.groupby(['store','product'])['amount'].diff()

But in order for this to work and show for example that the difference of c is -3 and -100%, c would need to be present on the next date with the amount set to 0

This is the results I am looking for:

```
print(df)
    store  product   amount   value    date
0     s1      a        1        1    2020-6-6
1     s1      a        2        2    2020-6-7
2     s1      b        3        3    2020-6-7
3     s2      c        5        5    2020-6-6
4     s2      b        2        2    2020-6-6
5     s2      b        3        3    2020-6-7
6     s2      c        0        0    2020-6-7
```

Comment: The first key of your dictionary should be `store` not `product`.

Comment: Is `df["date"].max()` give me the maximum date for all store (common date) or I need to get it per store?

Comment: @Corralien, it could be different based on the store, so it would need to be computed per store

Comment: Have you tested the solution to your question?

Comment: @Corralien I just went over the code, the logic makes sense. I will have access to the full dataset tomorrow and will test it. I will let you know once its tested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a few assumptions about your needs and what data you would be receiving. The first was that you only cared about filling in dates that were between the first date that an object was in stock, and the last day of interest(which for my program is considered the same for all stores). The second was that stock is not consistent between stores, but at some point in time all unique stock is carried at some point. Additionally I assumed that there was a possibility that the stock that goes missing can be restocked at some point before the end date. If any of these assumptions are wrong, they can be easily fixed in the code. The entire code is below for copy-paste convenience and an explanation is below that.

```
d = {'store': ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2'], 'product': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'], 'amount': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3], 'date': [6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

store_set = set(df['store'])
end_date = end_date = max(df['date'])
all_missing = []


for store in store_set:
   store_rows=df.loc[df['store'] == store]
   inventory = set(store_rows['product'])
   
   for product in inventory:
      product_rows=df.loc[df['product'] == product]
      product_dates = set(product_rows['date'])
      start_date = min(product_dates)
      need_dates = set(range(start_date,end_date+1))
      missing_dates = need_dates.difference(product_dates)
      for missing in missing_dates:         
         missing_row = [store,product,0,0,missing]
         all_missing.append(missing_row)
         
missing_frame = pd.DataFrame(all_missing, columns=df.columns)   
df=df.append(missing_frame)
```

Note: I changed the dates to integers for simplicity for the rest of the code, but you can very easily add code to read and write the strings.

```
d = {'store': ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2'], 'product': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'], 'amount': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3], 'date': [6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

store_set = set(df['store'])
end_date = end_date = max(df['date'])
all_missing = []
```

This initializes the set and creates a set of stores and what the last date that needs to have inventory filled to. Additionally it creates an empty list that will contain all the missing rows that will be appended to the data frame. This is done since pandas append is slower than normal append so we only want to do it once, but it is not needed.

```
for store in store_set:
   store_rows=df.loc[df['store'] == store]
   inventory = set(store_rows['product'])
   
   for product in inventory:
      product_rows=df.loc[df['product'] == product]
      product_dates = set(product_rows['date'])
```

These loops determine the unique items in each store and during which time periods they are in stock.

```
      start_date = min(product_dates)
      need_dates = set(range(start_date,end_date+1))
      missing_dates = need_dates.difference(product_dates)
```

This creates the set of dates that SHOULD have the product exist in that store(even if it is zero). For simplicity I assumed dates are continuous, but this can be easily fixed if that is not the case.

```
      for missing in missing_dates:         
         missing_row = [store,product,0,0,missing]
         all_missing.append(missing_row)
```

This adds the current product with 0 qty and value to the current store at each time it is missing

```
missing_frame = pd.DataFrame(all_missing, columns=df.columns)   
df=df.append(missing_frame)
```

Finally we have left the loop and appended all the missing data to the original frame. Note this is obviously not in order, but it can now be sorted to the desired configuration with pandas baked in functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this code is efficient at large scale but it does the job in a minimum of operations.

**TL;TR**

```
cols = ["store", "product", "date"]
df1 = df[df.groupby("store")["date"].apply(lambda store: store < store.max())]
df1 = df1.assign(amount=0, value=0, date=df["date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=1))
df1 = df[cols].merge(df1, on=cols, how="outer", indicator=True)
df1 = df1.loc[lambda x: x["_merge"] == "right_only"].drop(columns="_merge")
out = pd.concat([df, df1])
```

```
>>> out
  store product  amount  value       date
0    s1       a     1.0    1.0 2020-06-06
1    s1       a     2.0    2.0 2020-06-07
2    s1       b     3.0    3.0 2020-06-07
3    s2       c     5.0    5.0 2020-06-06
4    s2       b     2.0    2.0 2020-06-06
5    s2       b     3.0    3.0 2020-06-07
6    s2       c     0.0    0.0 2020-06-07
```

**Details**:

1. Remove all last date per store because we increment the date from one day at the next step. Dates must be in the same interval of already existing ones.

```
>>> df1 = df[df.groupby("store")["date"].apply(lambda store: store < store.max())]

  store product  amount  value       date
0    s1       a       1      1 2020-06-06
3    s2       c       5      5 2020-06-06
4    s2       b       2      2 2020-06-06
```

2. Increment date from one day

```
>>> df1 = df1.assign(amount=0, value=0, date=df["date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=1))

  store product  amount  value       date
0    s1       a       0      0 2020-06-07  # date already exist in df <- drop
3    s2       c       0      0 2020-06-07  # missing date in df <- keep
4    s2       b       0      0 2020-06-07  # date already exist in df <- drop
```

3. Find rows in `df1` which are not available in `df` (based on `cols`)

```
>>> df1 = df[cols].merge(df1, on=cols, how="outer", indicator=True)

  store product       date  amount  value      _merge
0    s1       a 2020-06-06     NaN    NaN   left_only
1    s1       a 2020-06-07     0.0    0.0        both
2    s1       b 2020-06-07     NaN    NaN   left_only
3    s2       c 2020-06-06     NaN    NaN   left_only
4    s2       b 2020-06-06     NaN    NaN   left_only
5    s2       b 2020-06-07     0.0    0.0        both
6    s2       c 2020-06-07     0.0    0.0  right_only  # keep it, drop others
```

4. Keep only dates which do not exist in `df` (`right_only` indicator):

```
>>> df1 = df1.loc[lambda x: x["_merge"] == "right_only"].drop(columns="_merge")

  store product       date  amount  value
6    s2       c 2020-06-07     0.0    0.0
```

5. Finally, merge the two dataframes `df` and `df1`:

```
>>> out = pd.concat([df, df1])

  store product  amount  value       date
0    s1       a     1.0    1.0 2020-06-06
1    s1       a     2.0    2.0 2020-06-07
2    s1       b     3.0    3.0 2020-06-07
3    s2       c     5.0    5.0 2020-06-06
4    s2       b     2.0    2.0 2020-06-06
5    s2       b     3.0    3.0 2020-06-07
6    s2       c     0.0    0.0 2020-06-07
```

**One-line version**:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df[cols].merge(df[df.groupby("store")["date"] \
                                       .apply(lambda store: store < store.max())] \
                                       .assign(amount=0, value=0, date=df["date"]+pd.DateOffset(days=1)),
                                  on=cols, how="outer", indicator=True) \
                           .loc[lambda x: x["_merge"] == "right_only"] \
                           .drop(columns="_merge")])

  store product  amount  value       date
0    s1       a     1.0    1.0 2020-06-06
1    s1       a     2.0    2.0 2020-06-07
2    s1       b     3.0    3.0 2020-06-07
3    s2       c     5.0    5.0 2020-06-06
4    s2       b     2.0    2.0 2020-06-06
5    s2       b     3.0    3.0 2020-06-07
6    s2       c     0.0    0.0 2020-06-07
```